# can web workers share external library files?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

In my application, I have multiple instances of the same web worker, which uses the underscore utility library. I am trying to keep each of the web workers from requesting their own copy of underscore from my server. Is there any way they can share external library resources?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the workers should share the external scripts automatically if you have proper cache headers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Answer (score 0):

whoops, looks like importScripts has been caching all this time, just had my dev tools open and had 'disable caching' checked...